# How to generate network interface config file?

Tags: configuration, network-interface

On CentOS, is there a way to generate again the network interface config files? 
The ones stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<ifaceName>`

It's quite easy to do manually:

- Get interface name with `ip link show`
- Create config file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<ifaceName>` with following content:

```
DEVICE="enp1s0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

But I assume it's possible to trigger some script to create them.
It will be handy when switching OS partition from one workstation to another  because if the network interfaces don't have the same name, we are unable to start network.